# How do I open existing VM in Google code editor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, editor, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine on Google servers, and I am tired of editing my files through the SSH client. I really like the way that Google Cloud Shell beta code editor looks and feels.

I was wondering if there was any way I could open and edit files from an existing virtual machine instance.

Comment: did you do it? can you tell me solution?

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51067700/9905745

Comment: did you find a solution?;

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Shell web-editor is just the open source [Orion editor](https://orionhub.org/) running on the the Cloud Shell VM.  You can install this editor on your VM and connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run vscode in browser locally with connection to remote google cloud vm instance. Needs to download [`code-server`](https://github.com/cdr/code-server) and the repo supplies a [binary version](https://github.com/cdr/code-server/releases). After downloading, you could install it on the GCP vm instance and run it in your browser.

Hope this [blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-run-visual-studio-code-in-google-cloud-shell-354d125d5748?) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=374&v=N5WojMutddQ&feature=emb_logo) will also help.