# Integrate Visual Studio Code into Google Cloud

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform

How can I interact with the code on my Google App Engine instance from Visual Studio Code?

Comment: When using Google Cloud code editor, you're actually editing code that resides on the [Google Compute Engine virtual machine](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/starting-cloud-shell#starting_a_new_session) provisioned for your Cloud Shell session. The code deployed to App Engine can't be interacted with directly, you have to deploy again either from the Cloud Shell virtual machine or from your local machine's Cloud SDK.

Comment: Ok thank you that makes sense.

Comment: Do you have an app deployed to Google Cloud App Engine or are you using Compute Engine virtual machines ? In any case, each time you make changes to the code, you will have to redeploy for the changes to come into effect. Have a look at Cloud Tools for Visual Studio if you would like to deploy directly from the IDE of Visual Studio - https://cloud.google.com/visual-studio/

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-the-ability-to-connect-to-cloud-shell-from-any-terminal

Comment: That is brilliant!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can now run Visual Studio Code from the Google Cloud Shell using
https://github.com/cdr/code-server/

It comes down to downloading `code-server`, starting it and using the Web Preview functionality of Google Cloud Shell to use it.

See also:
https://medium.com/@chees/how-to-run-visual-studio-code-in-google-cloud-shell-354d125d5748

Comment: nit: this is pointed out as a reply to the blog post, repeating here for convenience. Every mention of `linux-x64` should actually be `linux-x86_64`. Just add the `86_` and everything pretty much just falls into place.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SSHFS](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) to mount a remote directory on a Google Cloud Virtual Machine (VM). It is very easy to setup and use compared to VNC or FTP:

- First you have to access the VM via ssh. This is actually very easy and you don't need to generate any keys yourself. Just go to the console then: Compute Engine > VM Instances, then locate your instance and click on the SSH button at the far right. Tutorial and more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance).
- Install SSHFS on your machine. If you have a mac, you can use `brew cask install osxfuse` and then `brew install sshfs`.
- You are ready. Just type `sshfs [you_user_name]@[external_ip_of_vm]:[directory_on_vm_to_mount_to] [local_mount_point]`, eg. `sshfs john@35.222.222.1:/home/john ~/john-vm`.

If you decided to setup VNC, here is a [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5) to a very good tutorial on how to set it up on GC. And here is another link on how to setup [SFTP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8C66NwMJLs).

Answer (score 3):

You can check [VSCode remote](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) as well. It was recently developed and is already in quite stable stage. Probably [Remote SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) will help you the most in your case.